# How to compute some variations? From $\dot{f_\epsilon}=\dot{f}+\epsilon\dot{h}n+\epsilon h\dot{n}$ to $\delta\dot{f}=\dot{h}n+h\dot{n}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative, calculus-of-variations, variational-analysis

I have a paper and on that paper I only can read:

Let $f:\mathbb{S^{1}} \to \mathbb{R^2}$ be a function and $f_{\epsilon}=f+\epsilon hn$ where  $\mathbb{S^1}$ is the unit circle and $\dot{f}^2=r^2$. Further, we will denote $f_{\epsilon}(x)$ to be $f(\epsilon, x)$. Knowing that $f_{\epsilon}=f+\epsilon hn$ I want to compute some variations. $\delta f, \delta\dot{f}\text{ and }\delta r$.

- $\delta f:$
  $$\displaystyle f_{\epsilon}=f+\epsilon hn \Rightarrow \frac{f_{\epsilon}-f}{\epsilon}=hn\Rightarrow\delta f=hn$$
- $\delta\dot{f}:$
  $$\displaystyle \dot{f_{\epsilon}}=\dot{f}+\epsilon\dot{h}n+\epsilon h\dot{n}\Rightarrow \frac{\dot{f}-\dot{f}}{\epsilon}=\dot{h}n-\dot{h}n \Rightarrow \delta\dot{f}=\dot{h}n-h\dot{n}$$
- $\delta r:$ $$\displaystyle r_{\epsilon}^{2}=\left(\dot{f}+\epsilon\dot{h}n+\epsilon h\dot{n}\right)^2 \Rightarrow r_{\epsilon}^2=(\dot{f})^2+(\epsilon \dot{h}n)^2+(\epsilon h\dot{n})^2+2(\dot{f}\epsilon\dot{h}n+\dot{f}\epsilon h\dot{n}+\epsilon^2\dot{h}nh\dot{n})\Rightarrow r_{\epsilon}^2=r^2+(\epsilon \dot{h}n)^2+(\epsilon h\dot{n})^2+2(\dot{f}\epsilon\dot{h}n+\dot{f}\epsilon h\dot{n}+\epsilon^2\dot{h}nh\dot{n})\Rightarrow \frac{r_{\epsilon}^{2}-r^2}{\epsilon}=\epsilon((\dot{h}n)^2+(h\dot{n})^2+\dot{h}nh\dot{n})+2(\dot{f}\dot{h}n+\dot{f}h\dot{n})\Rightarrow\frac{r_{\epsilon}-r}{\epsilon}\cdot(r_{\epsilon}+r)=\epsilon((\dot{h}n)^2+(h\dot{n})^2+\dot{h}nh\dot{n})+2(\dot{f}\dot{h}n+\dot{f}h\dot{n})\Rightarrow \delta r(r_{\epsilon}+r)=\epsilon((\dot{h}n)^2+(h\dot{n})^2+\dot{h}nh\dot{n})+2(\dot{f}\dot{h}n+\dot{f}h\dot{n})$$

  $$\delta r(r_{\epsilon}+r)=\epsilon((\dot{h}n)^2+(h\dot{n})^2+\dot{h}nh\dot{n})+2(\dot{f}\dot{h}n+\dot{f}h\dot{n})$$

In the last equation I want to make $\epsilon \to 0$ and to say
$$2(\delta{r})r=2(\dot{f}\dot{h}n+\dot{f}h\dot{n})\Rightarrow \delta r=\frac{\dot{f}\dot{h}n+\dot{f}h\dot{n}}{r}.$$
This is what I tried. Could you please confirm if my computation are OK and if this is the true meaning of how variations can be computed?

Comment: $\delta f = \frac{f_\epsilon - f}{\epsilon}$.

Comment: @Ian  Thanks! So, more or less is the definition of the derivative? Also I managed to find another formula on another page but also anything else is not possible to be read from it...

Comment: I mean no, $\epsilon$ is fixed here.

Comment: you didn't award bounty last time

Comment: @mathworker21 Regarding that post I thought the bounty will be splitted automatically. Both answers helped me. This was the reason why I did not award the bounty last time.

Comment: Another Interesting information would be wether your function is in some Sobolev space. Usually, the sobolev spaces on a "1-dimensional domain" have nice properties.

Comment: @F.Conrad the function is not in Sobolev space. thanks